# Very slow iOS performance

Tags: ios, performance, optimization

I am on a team that is building an iOS app, and we are experiencing incredibly slow frame rates and unresponsiveness.  We have looked into many possible culprits and tried to simplify views, but it appears to be a very fundamental problem.  Even our login screen has a noticeable delay between the user's pressing a key and the character's appearing in one of the text fields.  On another screen that contains a map and a table view, the table view scrolls at only 5 FPS.

I know this is a very vague question, but we have not been able to make any headway.  Are there any things any of you have experienced that can cause such poor performance across the entire app?

I have thought about moving computation off the main thread, but I don't know how that would fix the unresponsive login screen, in which nothing should be happening after the view loads.

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments to profile your app?

Comment: I have, and have been unable to spot any obvious issues.  Memory and CPU usage are both low.

Comment: Performance issues can be due to various reasons like memory leaks, loading high size UIImage, making I/O calls in tableview cell creation etc. You might want to put some code which you think is causing issue. 

Quick question, is this observed on simulator, device or both?

Comment: Use the CPU time profiler, it is the best for finding the culprit of unresponsiveness.

Comment: This is observed on the simulator and the device as well. We have profiled it such that we see it doesn't take that much real memory, VM, or CPU time. The framerate tops out at like 9 FPS, whereas most apps that we've profiled against have upwards of 30 or 40FPS. Is it possibly a framework issue?

Comment: We have built this app in Xcode45-DP2 through 5 and the build target is both 5.1 and 6.0.

Comment: post some code that shows your biggest bottle neck.  Unless you are using a really old device you have serious code issues here.

Comment: I'm not sure where the biggest bottleneck is (locating it is the entire problem here), but I'll clean up the first UIViewController that is loaded and edit it into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the MFSideMenu library. (https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)

We were using an older version of this that did not include the line `controller.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:controller.view.bounds].CGPath;`, which meant the shadow rendering of this menu was not optimized.

Comment: I had this problem long ago, and fixed it in a similar way(some issue related to shadow), but now I'm wondering why was the issue and why the change above fixed it?